# use JSON_EXTRACT, JSON_SET, JSON_REPLACE, JSON_INSERT in json array

Tags: mysql, json

I have json type column in `mysql` named `names` and its a simple json array (not key/value). i couldn't find any example of using `JSON_EXTRACT`, `JSON_SET`, `JSON_REPLACE`, `JSON_INSERT` for simple json array field.

I know there are other ways to manipulate a json array in json field type, but is it possible to use these functions for json array?

for example, `name` field contains `["A","B","C"]`, how can I use these functions to perform an update, insert and delete on this json?

**update**

query must execute from a php script

Answer (score 3):

The functions you refer to all work exactly as expected and described in the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-functions.html); that is to say `JSON_SET` will insert or replace if a value already exists, `JSON_INSERT` will insert if a value doesn't already exist, and `JSON_REPLACE` will replace a pre-existing value. You can use `JSON_ARRAY_INSERT` and `JSON_ARRAY_APPEND` to more easily add values to a JSON array.

```sql
-- extract second element
select json_extract('["A", "B", "C"]', '$[1]')
-- "B"

-- replace second element
select json_set('["A", "B", "C"]', '$[1]', 'D')
-- ["A", "D", "C"]

-- insert fourth element
select json_set('["A", "B", "C"]', '$[3]', 'E')
-- ["A", "B", "C", "E"]

-- attempt to insert second element fails as it already exists
select json_insert('["A", "B", "C"]', '$[1]', 'F')
-- ["A", "B", "C"]

-- use json_array_insert to insert a new second element and move the other elements right
select json_array_insert('["A", "B", "C"]', '$[1]', 'F')
-- ["A", "F", "B", "C"]

-- insert fourth element
select json_insert('["A", "B", "C"]', '$[3]', 'F')
-- ["A", "B", "C", "F"]

-- or use json_array_append to add an element at the end
select json_array_append('["A", "B", "C"]', '$', 'F')
-- ["A", "B", "C", "F"]

-- replace second element
select json_replace('["A", "B", "C"]', '$[1]', 'G')
-- ["A", "G", "C"]

-- attempt to replace non-existing element fails
select json_replace('["A", "B", "C"]', '$[3]', 'G')
-- ["A", "B", "C"]
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=6795e2c8387dd56a75e5916f9de3a13c)

To use these functions on a column in a table, simply replace the `["A", "B", "C"]` in the above calls with the column name, for example:

```sql
create table test (j json);
insert into test values ('["A", "B", "C"]');
select json_array_insert(j, '$[1]', 'F') 
from test
-- ["A", "F", "B", "C"]
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=78eae9973fd8ab681e79bdc0a56d1b33)

Comment: thanks for your answer, I just update the question, i'm not running queries from the console but from a php script.
and i need to provide table name and field name.
can you example queries able to execute by script?
and what is `$[1]` and `$[3]`?

Comment: If you want to run a php script you can do it using fetch javascript command. The query is inserted in php script.

Comment: `json_array_insert` can be used to insert a new element in the middle of an array, like so: `json_array_insert('["A","B","C"]', '$[1]', 'D');`

Comment: @Guss you are right, I didn't talk about `json_array_insert` and `json_array_append` because OP was talking about a specific set of functions. However for completeness they should be in the answer so I've added them. Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 0):

i think found the solution

for json array, it's not possible to use `JSON_EXTRACT`, `JSON_SET`, `JSON_REPLACE`, `JSON_INSERT` by array values, and you have to know the place of each value in json array (in my opinion it's a weakness).

for example to select 2nd value you can use `$[1]`,
but for insert values you can use 
`JSON_ARRAY_APPEND`and `JSON_ARRAY_INSERT`